# Dynamic pivot query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a functioning pivot query for static column values which i want to convert for dynamic column values.

The query is :

```
with a as (

select  request_id, dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,logged_datetime),0) as 'Month'
,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,logged_datetime),0) as 'Year'

 from requests

 )


 select  * from (

 select datepart(m,a.Month) as 'months',datepart(YEAR,a.Year) as 'years',a.request_id

  from a  ) ps

 pivot (

 count(request_id) for [years] in ([2008],[2009],[2010],[2011],[2012],[2013],[2014],[2015])
 ) as pvt
 order by months
```

For the dynamic query written below I am getting errors like

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 Invalid column name '2010'. :

```
select distinct datepart(year,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,logged_datetime),0)) as 'Yearz'

into #t

FROM requests

DECLARE @Dynamic AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Yearz)
FROM (SELECT * from #t) AS Yea


SET @Dynamic = 
  N'

 select  * from (

 select datepart(m,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,logged_datetime),0)) as months,' + @ColumnName + ',request_id

  from requests ) ps

 pivot (

 count(request_id) for [Years] in (' + @ColumnName + ')
 ) as pvt
 order by months
'

EXEC sp_executesql @Dynamic
```

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: @NoDisplayName The dynamic query that Im trying is not working. Getting errors.

Comment: Found it remove  ` + @ColumnName + `  from pivot source query . Try this .`..select datepart(m,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,logged_datetime),0)) as months,request_id  from requests ..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
SELECT * INTO #REQUESTS
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 request_id, '2012-06-01' logged_datetime
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 request_id,  '2012-05-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 request_id, '2012-06-01' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 12 request_id,  '2012-05-01'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 request_id,  '2012-07-01' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 request_id,  '2013-09-01' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 request_id,  '2013-10-01' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6 request_id, '2014-01-01' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7 request_id,  '2014-02-01' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8 request_id, '2014-03-01' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9 request_id,  '2014-05-01' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 request_id,  '2015-11-01' 
)TAB
```

**QUERY**

Get the column for `years` and order it in numeric order

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + CAST([YEAR] AS VARCHAR(4)) + ']',  '[' + CAST([YEAR] AS VARCHAR(4)) + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,logged_datetime),0)) [YEAR] FROM #REQUESTS) PV  
               ORDER BY CAST([YEAR] AS INT)
```

Now pivot the query

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             ( 
                 -- We will get the count for a year and number of request_id in that month here as CNT column
                 select DISTINCT datepart(m,a.Month) as ''months'',datepart(YEAR,a.Year) as ''years'',
                COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY datepart(YEAR,a.Year),datepart(m,a.Month)) CNT
                 from
                 (
                    select  request_id, dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,logged_datetime),0) as ''Month''
                    ,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,logged_datetime),0) as ''Year''
                     from #requests
                 )a 
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(CNT)
                 FOR years IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY MONTHS;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef056/2) to view the result

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wrap your dynamic column names using the [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function:

See example [here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/dynamic-pivot-on-multiple-columns/):

Comment: `Quotename` is used. `+ QUOTENAME(Yearz)
FROM (SELECT * from #t) `